# Error with UserManager::__construct() in PUGXMultiUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle, pugxmultiuserbundle

Sorry if my english in't very good. I'm learning it.

I have followed all the steps of the instalation guide of PUGXMultiUserBundle. The only thing i haven`t done is to create the forms for my entities. I'm confused about it.

When I go to the register page for my user-one, it says this to me:

> **Catchable Fatal Error**: Argument 1 passed to
>   FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\UserManager::__construct() must implement
>   interface
>   Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactoryInterface,
>   instance of FOS\UserBundle\Util\PasswordUpdater given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\vendor\pugx\multi-user-bundle\Doctrine\UserManager.php
>   on line 44 and defined

Code of PUGXMultiUserBundle's User Manager:

```
// vendor\pugx\multi-user-bundle\Doctrine\UserManager.php (function __construct)

 public function __construct(PasswordUpdaterInterface $passwordUpdater, CanonicalFieldsUpdater $canonicalFieldsUpdater, ObjectManager $om, $class, UserDiscriminator $userDiscriminator)
    {
        $this->om = $om;
        $this->userDiscriminator = $userDiscriminator;

        parent::__construct($passwordUpdater, $canonicalFieldsUpdater, $om, $class);
    }
```

Code of FOSUserBundle's User Manager:

```
// vendor\friendsofsymfony\user-bundle\Doctrine\UserManager.php (function __construct)

public function __construct(EncoderFactoryInterface $encoderFactory, CanonicalizerInterface $usernameCanonicalizer, CanonicalizerInterface $emailCanonicalizer, ObjectManager $om, $class)
    {
        parent::__construct($encoderFactory, $usernameCanonicalizer, $emailCanonicalizer);

        $this->objectManager = $om;
        $this->repository = $om->getRepository($class);

        $metadata = $om->getClassMetadata($class);
        $this->class = $metadata->getName();
    }
```

Comment: Which is the line 44 in pugx\multi-user-bundle\Doctrine\UserManager.php ?

Comment: In the file `pugx\multi-user-bundle\Doctrine\UserManager.php` you give the first parameter to `parent::_construct` as an `PasswordUpdaterInterface` instance variable instead of an `EncoderFactoryInterface` instance var.

I hope you understand what I mean

Comment: I tried it before, but if I substitute the params of the PUGXMultiUserBundle's __construct function  with the params of FOSUsersBundle's __construct function, it says this to me: **Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to PUGX\MultiUserBundle\Doctrine\UserManager::__construct() must be an instance of PUGX\MultiUserBundle\Doctrine\EncoderFactoryInterface, instance of FOS\UserBundle\Util\PasswordUpdater given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\CASPruebas\app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 2197 and defined**

Comment: line 44 is that: `parent::__construct($passwordUpdater, $canonicalFieldsUpdater, $om, $class);`